# Get Class Name with extension in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, class, reflection, stack-frame

I am trying to get class name with the extension (e.g. Employee.cs or Employee.aspx.cs) in my code. I was able to get the name of the class **without the extension** but does anybody know how can i also get extension of the class??

This is what i did to get class name:

```
var frame = new StackFrame(1);
string className = frame.GetMethod().ReflectedType.Name;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call [`frame.GetFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.getfilename.aspx).
This will only work if you have the PDB file.

Answer (score 5):

That is not possible with reflection. The name of the source compilation file is not part of the metadata of the type.